# How to implement time delay into Verilog FSM

Tags: time, verilog, delay, fsm, state-machine

```
always @(posedge clock)
    case(state)
        `STATE0: begin
            state <= `STATE1;
            // Code here
            // Wait 5ms before advancing 
        end
        `STATE1: begin 
            state <= `STATE2;
            // Code here
            // Wait 5ns before advancing 
        end
        `STATE2: begin 
            state <= `STATE0;
            // Code here
            // Wait 5s before advancing 
        end
        default:begin
            state <= `STATE0;
            // Code here
        end
    endcase
end
```

Is it possible to add wait statements into the design where it must wait x amount of time units before it can proceed to the next state? 
I know it can be manually done in my testbench using `#` but my design requires that there needs to be a certain wait time before I can proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For short delays (a few clock cycles), it might be easiest to implement a few "dummy" states as intermediaries between the intended states.

For longer delays, use a counter as the enable signal to transfer between the states:

```
reg [31:0] count;
always@(posedge clock)
    if (SOME RESET) count <=0;
    else count <= count + 1;

always @(posedge clock)
//...
   STATE_N: if (count == SOME_NUMBER_OF_CYCLES) state <= STATE_NPLUSONE;
            else state <= STATE_N;
```